# How do I submit this PHP poll form on click of a radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using CSS Tricks' [How To Design and Create a PHP Powered Poll](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-design-and-create-a-php-powered-poll/) tutorial to create my own poll.

I'm trying to get the poll to submit when the user clicks one of the radio button options, instead of submitting when they click the "Vote" button.

**poll.php:**

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conn_vote.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO poll (id, question) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Poll'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_conn_vote, $conn_vote);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conn_vote) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "results.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

$colname_rs_vote = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['recordID'])) {
  $colname_rs_vote = $_GET['recordID'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_conn_vote, $conn_vote);
$query_rs_vote = sprintf("SELECT * FROM poll WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_vote, "int"));
$rs_vote = mysql_query($query_rs_vote, $conn_vote) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_vote = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_vote);
$totalRows_rs_vote = mysql_num_rows($rs_vote);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Poll</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Poll" value="snoppdogg" id="Poll_0" />
      Snoop Dogg
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Poll" value="biggie" id="Poll_1" />
      Biggie
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Poll" value="tupac" id="Poll_2" />
      Tupac
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Vote" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="form1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
mysql_free_result($rs_vote);
?>
```

**conn_vote.php:**

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_conn_vote = "localhost";
$database_conn_vote = "poll";
$username_conn_vote = "root";
$password_conn_vote = "root";
//$conn_vote = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn_vote, $username_conn_vote, $password_conn_vote) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$conn_vote = mysql_connect($hostname_conn_vote, $username_conn_vote, $password_conn_vote) or die('Can\'t create connection: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_conn_vote, $conn_vote) or die('Can\'t access specified db: '.mysql_error());
?>
```

Here's what poll.php looks like:

[image]

This works great if you click "Vote", but not if you just click a radio button.

I also tried adding an onchange event to each radio input, but that doesn't actually submit the form either.

```
<input onchange="this.form.submit();" type="radio" name="Poll" value="snoopdogg" id="Poll_0" />
```

I have a feeling that it has to do with the hidden inputs, but I can't figure out what needs to change.

Any ideas on how to submit the form when the user clicks a radio button?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I think it's a PHP issue, not a JavaScript issue. I've tried all of these JavaScript solutions and none of them have worked:

```
<input onchange="this.form.submit();" type="radio" name="Poll" value="snoopdogg" id="Poll_0" />
```

and

```
<input onClick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" name="Poll" value="snoopdogg" id="Poll_0" />
```

and

```
$('input').click(function(){
  $('form').submit();
});
```

and

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  $("form").submit();
});
```

and

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

and

```
$('input').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'results.php',
    data:{radio:info}
    }).done(function(data){
      alert("show that ajax call was successful!");
    });
  });
```

By "submit", I mean that I want it to submit the form, enter the values into the database, and go to the results.php page, which is currently the functionality of the "Vote" button.

Comment: Instead of trying to turn a radio button into something it isn't, use three normal buttons.

Comment: @zzzzBov you can do it.

Comment: @zzzzBov I was actually going to eventually style the radio inputs as traditional buttons, so that's a good suggestion. But, the reason I was keeping them as radio buttons is because I wanted to be semantic--since the poll is a "select one answer" form, I thought that radio buttons would be the right choice. What do you think?

Comment: If it looks like a button, and acts like a button, it's a button.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onClick` instead of `onChange`.

```
<input onChange="this.form.submit();" />
```

You can also use jQuery to submit the form onClick:

```
$('input').click(function(){
  $('form').submit();
});
```

And for something more slick, use AJAX ;)

```
$('input').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'somePage.php',
    data:{radio:info}
    }).done(function(data){
        //show that ajax call was successful!
     });
  });
```

[AJAX DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wyfoLyzd/1/)

**EDIT:** I guess your problem was with your PHP code, since it wasn't inserting the values into the database. The reason why your form wasn't submitting though, was because you used `onChange` instead of `onClick`.

If you want to use AJAX, you need to get the values from the input elements, in this case the radio inputs. You do NOT have to submit the form when you use AJAX.

For instance:

```
<input type="radio" id="#tupacRadio" />
//get the value of the radio input
var tupacRadio = $('#tupacRadio').val();
```

Then once you call AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  data:{value:tupacRadio}
})
```

Comment: I agree Ajax is the way to go here.  You can do many cool things like hide the form after it was submitted and display statistical data afterward.

Comment: @Rafael I use AJAX for everything now ;)

Comment: It certainly is the future of web development especially with the creation of NoSQL databases like MongoDB

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried all of these solutions but unfortunately none of them work in the context of my full code. Clicking "Vote" submits the values into the database table, but clicking a radio button does not. Nothing changes when I click a radio button. Perhaps I should have elaborated on what I meant by "submit"--I'm looking for a solution that submits the form and enters the values into the database, which is the intended functionality of the poll. I believe at this point that it's a PHP problem, since I've tried all of the suggested jQuery/JavaScript scripts to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

HTML DOC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Poll</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <label> Snoop Dogg
        <input type="radio" name="Poll" value="snoop" id="Poll_0" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Poll" value="biggie" id="Poll_1" /> Biggie
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Poll" value="tupac" id="Poll_2" /> Tupac
      </label>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        $("#form").ajaxSubmit({url: 'send.php', type: 'post'})
        $("#form").replaceWith("<h2>Thank you for your vote!</h2>");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

SEND.PHP

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

// Radio 
$poll = $_POST['Poll'];

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

function pollQuery($value) {
  $sql = "";
  if ($value == "snoop") {
    $sql = "UPDATE poll SET snoop = snoop + 1 WHERE id = 1";
    return $sql;
  } elseif ($value == "biggie") {
    $sql = "UPDATE poll SET biggie = biggie + 1 WHERE id = 1";
    return $sql;
  } else {
    $sql = "UPDATE poll SET tupac = tupac + 1 WHERE id = 1";
    return $sql;
  }
}

if ( isset($poll) ) {
  // Run Query
  $conn->query( pollQuery($poll) );
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

---

CONNECTION.PHP

```
<?php
// Connect info
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "poll";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
?>
```

Comment: This is the jQuery that I already have in the HTML above:

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
  </script>

Unfortunately changing "$(this).closest("form").submit();" to "$("form").submit();" didn't change anything.

Comment: @AnnaBlabber My example is working in the link I provided.  Check your code and try again.

Comment: I see that it is working there, but it's not working for me in the context of my full files. It's not entering any values into my database table, whereas clicking "Vote" enters values.

After trying many variations of "submit form on radio button click" scripts to no avail, it appears that there's it's not an issue with JavaScript, but with the PHP.

Comment: make sure in your php code your not using `if(isset($_POST['SubmitName'])) { // insert values in db}`

Comment: I am using that:

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) { ...

The tutorial didn't explain how that code works so I'm trying to figure out how it affects the form submission.

Comment: post the code in your question i'll help you out.  Ill be back in 2 hours I have to go to class now

Comment: It's all up there in poll.php. Thanks @Rafael!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66068/discussion-between-rafael-and-annablabber).

Comment: I've downvoted because you assume the file only has 1 form. You should use `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {$(this.form).submit();});` instead.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I didn't assume anything.  This is how she said it would be.

Comment: I will remove my downvote. But at least instruct about this. Just a warning saying that this code is made only for this and only this page (without being merged into any other page). From what I read, she blindly copied the code and dumped it on her files. Any Javascript or PHP issue is easily detected using the element inspector. Educate a little. It won't hurt.